# Unable to import tf.keras.backend within colab

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

The code is returning errors when attempting to import tensorflow.keras.backend

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-4a7085226070> in <cell line: 6>()
      4 from keras.layers import Dense
      5 import os
----> 6 from tensorflow.keras.backend import set_session
      7 from keras.optimizers import SGD, Adagrad, Nadam, Adadelta
      8 from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint

ImportError: cannot import name 'set_session' from 'tensorflow.keras.backend' (/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/api/_v2/keras/backend/__init__.py)
```

I tried installing pip packages but it still did not fix the issues. I believe it is a problem with the version and my code being outdated.

Comment: In general, it is not a good idea to mix stand-alone Keras with `tensorflow.keras`.